# How can I remove certain search results Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

Essentially, I want to exclude certain programs from showing in the search results. I still want to use the search feature for everything else.

For example.  don't show `solitare`, when I type in `sol`...... etc

Comment: Already added the startmenu folder I want to exclude, and I rebuilt the index....still appears in the search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://freewindowsvistatutorials.com/hideGamesFromStartMenuInWindows7.php

Simply delete the shorcut/entire folder in question from the `C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` directory.

It's just that easy.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it

- Search for Indexing Options and run it
- When the window opens Click the Modify button
- on the Indexed Locations window, click "Show all Locations"
- When the window reopens, Click the start menu in the bottom frame, then in the top frame, find the programs or folders not to index and clear the check boxes.
- Click Ok & Close to get back out

Comment: The Show All Locations button is greyed out for me....

Comment: You do need local admin rights to make this change

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stop individual files and folders from being indexed by assigning the `I` attribute.

```
attrib +i c:\foo.exe
```